# How do I find the right syntax for my mysql version ?

Tags: mysql, linux, fedora-26

I want to create a database for a simple authentication system but I just keep getting errors regarding the syntax and I can't find the appropriate one.

I connect to MySQL using : `mysql -u root -p` 
with the password being : `R2pay(XF%jVh`(I got it at some point don't remember how)

Then I type `CREATE DATABASE Filelist;` and I get this error :

> ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.

So I am like okay, I just have to change my password, but things get worse.

When I type this `SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD ('123456');` I get :

> ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements

I try to use a different method with `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'elma3alem' PASSWORD EXPIRE;` and I get :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'elma3alem' PASSWORD EXPIRE' at line 3

Even when I try to fix the "policy" problem with `uninstall plugin validate_password;` for example I get another error :

> ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.

I am really getting desperate, everytime I try to find a solution I end up with even more errors, can't even count how much time I spent trying to fix mysql problems...

BTW this is what `mysql --version displays` :

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements
Means you paswword is too simple did you tryed another one like 'Draga123456'?

Comment: I wish it was that simple, it still displays the same error :/

Answer (score 0):

At last ,I find it....
In this doc: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html
this command works:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```

enjoy it!